# Why are the printed values all junk? How can we fix this?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering.
You see, we made a program for a game called Magic number game (3x3). But in our program, the user will input all nine numbers and the program will check whether the inputted numbers all summed up to 15 when added horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

We got the right algorithm using the simple `cin/cout` method, having the correct output, but we are required to use classes.

When we did it, the input is correct, but when the numbers and sums are printed, the program prints garbage memories, not getting what the users input. Here are the codes we have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
class magicNumber {
public:
    void inputNum(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
    void check();
    void displayResults();
    void decision();
    magicNumber();

private:
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2;
};
magicNumber::magicNumber() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = 0;
    int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2 = 0;
}

void magicNumber::inputNum(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) {
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the first row (seperate by space): ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the next row (seperate by space):  ";
    cin >> d >> e >> f;
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the last row (seperate by space):  ";
    cin >> g >> h >> i;
    cout << endl;
}
void magicNumber::check() {
    int check = 0;
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2;
    row1 = a + b + c;
    if (row1 != 15)
        (check++);

    row2 = d + e + f;
    if (row2 != 15)
        (check++);

    row3 = g + h + i;
    if (row3 != 15)
        (check++);

    col1 = a + d + g;
    if (col1 != 15)
        (check++);

    col2 = b + e + h;
    if (col2 != 15)
        (check++);

    col3 = c + f + i;
    if (col3 != 15)
        (check++);

    dia1 = c + e + g;
    if (dia1 != 15)
        (check++);

    dia2 = a + e + i;
    if (dia2 != 15)
        (check++);
}

void magicNumber::displayResults() {
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2;

    cout << "                        = " << dia1 << "\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << a << "   +   " << b << "   +   " << c << "   + = " << row1
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << d << "   +   " << e << "   +   " << f << "   + = " << row2
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << g << "   +   " << h << "   +   " << i << "   + = " << row3
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "  = " << col1 << "    = " << col2 << "    = " << col3 << "    = "
         << dia2 << "\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
void magicNumber::decision() {

    int check = 0;
    char ans;
    if (check != 0) {
        cout << "YOU FAILED. TRY AGAIN? [Y/N]: ";
        cin >> ans;

        switch (ans) {
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                int main();

            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                cout << "\nTHANK YOU, PLAY AGAIN!!";
                break;
        }

    }

    else if (check == 0)
        cout << "YOU WON!! CONGRATULATIONS!\n\n";
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    system("CLS");

    int check;
    char ans;

    magicNumber numbers;

    cout << "Welcome to Magic Square Number game!\n"
         << "Please fill out the 3 x 3 grid with numbers \n"
         << "1 to 9 without repeating any digits. The sum\n"
         << " should be 15 when the numbers are added horizontally, \n"
         << "vertically, or diagonally.\n\n";

    numbers.inputNum(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    numbers.check();
    numbers.displayResults();
    numbers.decision();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You are declaring local variables of the same name as member variables. **DON'T**.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring the integer variables locally in every routine. This not only hides the member variables, but initializes them to whatever was on the stack before them. The proper fix would be to remove them, and utilize the member variables instead.

In practice it is helpful to put some kind of prefix/suffix on class member variables to distinguish them from local variables. some examples:

```
class Foo
{
    int fVariable;
    int variable_;
    int variable_m;
    int m_variable;
};
```

With those kinds of decorations it is much easier to discern the scope and ownership of a variable:

```
void Foo::ClassRoutine()
{
    int variable;

    variable = 0; // local variable
    variable_m = 0; // class member variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared these member variables:

```
class magicNumber
{
  //... 
  int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
  int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2;
```

Then, in `check()`:

```
void magicNumber::check()
{
  int check = 0;
  int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
```

and in `displayResults()`:

```
void magicNumber::displayResults()
{   
  int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
```

You declare local variables with the same names. The shared `a`, `b`, etc. are never looked at or touched by either method.

Remove the local declarations so the member variables are used instead.

```
void magicNumber::displayResults()
{   
  cout<<"                        = "<<dia1<<"\n";
  // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. We'll try to apply all what you have told me to improve our program.

Answer (score 0):

For the immediate problem, just remove the local variables of the same names as member variables.

---

Since you were told to use a class, I think I'd better comment on that.

You have used the class mechanism to implement a *procedural* logic: do that, then do that, and so on.

But think about, if the console i/o was replaced with a GUI, how useful would this class be then? For that matter, how useful is it now? The answer, it's not very useful, it's just a complication.

Instead think of an object of a class as an automation, with some internal state (private data members) and some visible buttons (public member functions). Pushing any button makes the automation do something, possibly changing its internal state. In this particular case a useful internal state would be the 9 values, and a useful "button" could be a member function that reported, via a `bool` function result, whether those numbers constituted a magic square.

Other functionality could include setting the numbers.

---

Finally, you might want to consider `std::array` for holding the numbers, and loops to do the checking.

Comment: Thanks! We finally managed to fix the bug thanks to all of you. Thanks for the tips also sir. We're grateful for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems in the code:

- You are declaring variables with the same name that the member variables of the class `magicNumber` in the methods of that class. I assume that you only want to use the member variables and not hiding (when you declare a variable in inner scope with the same name that one of outer scope the later is hide and the former is visible in the inner scope).
- You are falling through the case statement in the `decision` method. When you call `main()` you are always later execute `cout << "\nTHANK YOU, PLAY AGAIN!!";`.
- It's really, really a bad idea to call the `main` method. Extract the functionality you need to call to other method.

Fixed code (don't know if it work, `check` method is unfinish for what I can see, but compile OK and fix the problem described):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gameplay();

using namespace std;
class magicNumber {
public:
    void inputNum(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
    void check();
    void displayResults();
    void decision();
    magicNumber();

private:
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    int row1, row2, row3, col1, col2, col3, dia1, dia2;
};
magicNumber::magicNumber() {
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = 0;
    row1 = row2 = row3 = col1 = col2 = col3 = dia1 = dia2 = 0;
}

void magicNumber::inputNum(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) {
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the first row (seperate by space): ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the next row (seperate by space):  ";
    cin >> d >> e >> f;
    cout << "Enter three numbers for the last row (seperate by space):  ";
    cin >> g >> h >> i;
    cout << endl;
}
void magicNumber::check() {
    int check = 0;
    row1 = a + b + c;
    if (row1 != 15)
        (check++);

    row2 = d + e + f;
    if (row2 != 15)
        (check++);

    row3 = g + h + i;
    if (row3 != 15)
        (check++);

    col1 = a + d + g;
    if (col1 != 15)
        (check++);

    col2 = b + e + h;
    if (col2 != 15)
        (check++);

    col3 = c + f + i;
    if (col3 != 15)
        (check++);

    dia1 = c + e + g;
    if (dia1 != 15)
        (check++);

    dia2 = a + e + i;
    if (dia2 != 15)
        (check++);
}

void magicNumber::displayResults() {
    cout << "                        = " << dia1 << "\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << a << "   +   " << b << "   +   " << c << "   + = " << row1
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << d << "   +   " << e << "   +   " << f << "   + = " << row2
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+   " << g << "   +   " << h << "   +   " << i << "   + = " << row3
         << "\n";
    cout << "+       +       +       +\n";
    cout << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    cout << "  = " << col1 << "    = " << col2 << "    = " << col3 << "    = "
         << dia2 << "\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
void magicNumber::decision() {

    int check = 0;
    char ans;
    if (check != 0) {
        cout << "YOU FAILED. TRY AGAIN? [Y/N]: ";
        cin >> ans;

        switch (ans) {
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                gameplay();
                break;

            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                cout << "\nTHANK YOU, PLAY AGAIN!!";
                break;
        }

    }

    else if (check == 0)
        cout << "YOU WON!! CONGRATULATIONS!\n\n";
    cout << endl;
}

void gameplay() {
    magicNumber numbers;

    cout << "Welcome to Magic Square Number game!\n"
         << "Please fill out the 3 x 3 grid with numbers \n"
         << "1 to 9 without repeating any digits. The sum\n"
         << " should be 15 when the numbers are added horizontally, \n"
         << "vertically, or diagonally.\n\n";

    numbers.inputNum(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    numbers.check();
    numbers.displayResults();
    numbers.decision();
}

int main() {
    system("CLS");

    gameplay();

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Some other recommendation:

- You need to use a loop in `decision` method to repeat the game if the user want to.